# Find a graph with at least two vertices and no self-loops in which all vertices have different degrees

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

I am an high-school senior interested in Graph Theory, on a web forum a CS teacher teased me with ("an easy but non-trivial") a terrific Graph Theory problem:

> Find a graph with at least two vertices and no self-loops in which all vertices have different degrees, or prove that no such graphs exist.

The problem is that I can't find a way to prove my conjecture (which state that such graph don't exist). I tried  to reformulate the problem into the following statement, that looks much simpler to me

> Prove that in any graph with at least two vertices and no self-loops there is two vertices of the same degree

As of today, I also thought about showing that the graph can't be finite because there is no "equilibrium state" (I don't know if it makes sense in English) were all edges/vertices are compensating each other and satisfying the constraint of the problem.

**I am afraid of searching the web**, because I don't want to be spoiled the solution by Proof-wiki or some forum, it would be infuriating since I find the problem **super fun!**

I suspect that I may lack the mathematical maturity to solve it or the knowledge since I (sadly) discovered Graph theory two weeks ago, I only know the very basics of GT (Chapter 6 and 7.1 of [*Mathematics for Computer Science*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos340/LL.pdf) by Eric Lehmand and Tom Leigthon).

This is probably a good thing to try out such problem without being comfortable with Graph Theory proofs because I could come up with a creative way of solving it but that's also kind of a torture since I feel somewhat stuck right now, exterior help would be appreciated.

**Could you please give me hints/ideas to explore?**

*Please do not disclose too much information (like "use induction on X", "that's trivial, just use theorem X")!*

PS: Sorry for any grammar faults!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need some more conditions on the graph.  As the problem is stated, I can find such a graph with three vertices-draw two edges between A and B, then an edge from A to C.  I think the problem wants to rule this out.

Comment: @Ross Doesn't unqualified “graph” mean “simple graph”?

Comment: @MJD:  I don't know.  If so, that suffices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to give a good hint about this without giving the whole game away, but I'll try:

> Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices.  What are the possible degrees of vertices of $G$?

I suppose you've tried drawing a graph where all vertices had different degree. What went wrong?  (If you haven't tried, then the hint is: try!)